# Angular 2/Karma "By.directive" - How to Select an Html Element?

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I am looking at the Angular 2 [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#attribute-directive):

```
fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(HighlightDirective));
```

However, when I try it, `By` is undefined. What import do I need? Also, I assume I am correct in understanding that this lets me select individual html elements in the template by directive/class/id/etc?

is there some other way to select an html element and trigger actions on it? (E.g. 'click')

Answer (score 4):

Well, turns out that it WAS in the docs, but it took a while to find it. The import is:

```
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```